# Questions on jSoupLink

Tags: packages, webtools

I try to use jSoupLink to scrap data. However, I have difficulty in using `ParseHTML` commamd.

For example, I cant get the `ParseHTML` to work

```
ParseHTML[
 "https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1921/einstein-facts.html", 
 "span[itemprop=birthDate]", 
 "text"
 ]
```

I would appreciate any help on this as I am new to jSoupLink.

Comment: `ParseHTML` is a syntax that was used in an old version of jsoupLink. Please see [the documentation](https://github.com/cekdahl/jSoupLink) for the up syntax to be used with the current version.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. May I further ask what will be the syntax when using about example ?

Comment: You can try this: `el = Import[url, "HTMLDOM"]; spans = el["Select", "span[itemprop=birthDate]"; birthDates = #["AllText"] & /@ spans; ` When looking at the URL in your question, I don't find any such span element, however. (Also, I haven't tried this code in Mathematica, which I don't have access to at the moment.)

Comment: I try to code,but fail. I reckon the problem is the span element as I was referring to an old post on using jSoupLink, So I were to get the 'Facts' (https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1921/einstein/facts/) using jSoupLink, what should be the right command ?

Comment: By looking at the HTML code, you can tell that 1) the facts (e.g. year of birth) aren't wrapped in span elements, and 2) that the <p> tags that wrap facts do not have attributes that identify them. You'll have to look at other pages as well and see if you can find pattern. For example, `el["Select", "article.facts p"]` will (although I haven't tested it) give you a list of `p` elements where each element has a fact in it. Perhaps it's the case that the second of those elements is always the one with the year of birth. Perhaps there is no pattern, in which case...

Comment: ...you can use `facts = el["Select", "article.facts"]; text = facts["AllText"];` and then parse the year of birth, and other facts, from that piece of text.